# If $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous then $f$ is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

**My attempt**

Let $X=\{x \in [a,b]; f|[a,x]$ is bounded $\}$.

We have $a\in X$ and $X \subset [a,b] \Rightarrow$  $X$ is non-empty and bounded.

Therefore
there exists $c = \sup X \leq b$.

We have:

**1)** $c \in X$;

Indeed, take $\varepsilon = 1$, since $f$ is continuous at $c$, there
exists $\delta>0$ such that
$x \in (c-\delta, c + \delta) \cap [a,b] \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(c)| < 1$.

Since $c-\delta<c$, there exists $y\in X$ such that $c-\delta<y\leq c$.  Since $y \in X$ we have $f|[a,y]$ bounded.

$f|(y,c]$ is also bounded:
Let $x\in (y,c] \subset (c-\delta, c + \delta).$
Then  $|f(x)| \leq |f(x)-f(c)| + |f(c)|  < |f(c)| + 1$.
Therefore $f|(y,c]$ is bounded.

Thus $f|[a,c]$ is bounded $\Rightarrow c \in X$.

**2)** $c=b$;

By contradiction, let's suppose that $c<b$.

Take $\varepsilon = 1$, since $f$ is continuous at $c$, there
exists $\delta>0$ such that
$x \in (c-\delta, c + \delta) \cap [a,b] \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(c)| < 1$.

Let $y \in (c, \min \{ c + \delta, b\})$. We have $y\in [a,b]$.

$f|[a,c]$ is bounded since $c \in X$.

$f|(c,y]$ is also bounded:

Let $x \in (c, y] \subset  (c-\delta, c + \delta)
\cap [a,b]$.
Then $|f(x)| \leq |f(x)-f(c)| + |f(c)|  < |f(c)| + 1 $. Therefore
$f|(c,y]$ is bounded.

Thus $f|[a,y]$ is bounded$ \Rightarrow y\in X$. We have $y>c = \sup X$, which is a contradiction,

Then $c=b$.

**3)** $X=[a,b]$.

Indeed, let $x \in [a,b]$. So $f([a,x]) \subset f([a,b])$. Since
 $f([a,b])$ is bounded  we have  $f|[a,b]$ bounded $\Rightarrow x \in X$.

Thus,  $X=[a,b]$.

Am I right?

Comment: in first line..X is a just a subset (not necessarily proper) the way you define....then do give the equality sign in the second line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it seems correct. You're basically using the fact that a continuous function is “locally bounded”.

Here's how I might write it.

**Lemma.** *For every $c\in[a,b]$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $f$ is bounded on $(c-\delta,c+\delta)\cap[a,b]$.*

*Proof.* By continuity of $f$ at $c$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that, for $x\in(c-\delta,c+\delta)\cap[a,b]$,
$$
|f(x)-f(c)|<1
$$
and therefore $f(c)-1<f(x)<f(c)+1$. QED

Consider the set $X=\{y\in[a,b]: f|_{[a,y]}\text{ is bounded}\}$. Then $a\in X$ and therefore $c=\sup X$ exists. Suppose $c<b$ and take $\delta>0$ such that $f$ is bounded on $(c-\delta,c+\delta)\cap[a,b]$.

By definition of supremum, there exists $y_1\in X$ with $c-\delta<y\le c$. Then $f$ is bounded on $[a,y_1]$, but also on $(c-\delta,c+\delta)$. Since $c<b$, there exists $y_2\in(c,c+\delta)$, $y_2<b$. But then $f$ is also bounded on $[y_1,y_2]$ and therefore it is bounded on $[a,y_2]$. So $y_2\in X$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see any problems with it on first glance. However, you should consider starting your proof by contradiction, like this: suppose $f$ is not bounded on $[a,b]$, then $\ldots$

If you then use Bolzano-Weierstrass, you'll get a much shorter (and more elegant) proof of the same result.